# Microsoft Data Quality Services Refresh of client view table error

Tags: sql-server, windows, client, data-quality-services

I am trying to run SQL Server Data Quality Services on SQL Server 2014 with 32GB of RAM, plenty of disk space, and the latest updates (Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-CU2) (KB3188778) - 12.0.5522.0 (X64) Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor))
The data resides on the same server, separate database.
Knowledge base is created and published with three domains over about a million records table. And that where it stops working: creating data quality project fails after displaying cheerful message "Analysis of data source has been completed successfully" - clicking "Next" button leads to message #1, and, after restarting the application (and the server - just in case), the message #2

1. SQL Server Data Quality Services server has stopped working
2. Refresh of client view table for user [domain\user] failed.

These are fairly consistent.
Examining both the server and the client logs reveals nothing (besides a full stack dump for the error), and the only suggestion from Microsoft forums is “to apply latest service pack”; the latest service pack has been applied but still no cigar.

Any insights/suggestions would be highly appreciated!

thank you,
-al

P.S. Excerpt from the client log:
2/13/2017 9:19:26 AM|[]|1|ERROR|CLIENT|Microsoft.Ssdqs.Studio.ViewModels.Utilities.UIHelper|An error has occurred.
Microsoft.Ssdqs.Infra.Exceptions.EntryPointException: Refresh of client view table for user [domain\user] failed.;
   at Microsoft.Ssdqs.Proxy.Database.DBAccessClient.Exec();

Answer (score 0):

After poking around I have found a question similar to my on MSDN blog: a user complained that his DQS installation has STOPPED working after applying CU2 to his SQL Server 2014 instance... So, I downgraded mine from [(SP2-CU2) (KB3188778)] to [(SP2) (KB3171021)], and - drums rolling - everything started working!

This is not a solution but an acceptable workaround, and I can continue analyzing my data until I upgrade to SQL Server 2016, and the fun begins anew!